# Groovy installation failure on windows

Tags: groovy, installation

Wizard run nicely but Groovy does not start.

I tried to install Groovy to my Windows.

I installed first Java (jdk-8u381-windows-x64) and then tried to install Groovy from here:
https://groovy.apache.org/download.html and more specific using this installer
https://groovy.jfrog.io/artifactory/dist-release-local/groovy-windows-installer/groovy-4.0.15/

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: "_Groovy does not start_" You're going to need to copy error messages, etc to here, otherwise all you're going to get is downvotes and guesses

Comment: I am new to Groovy so this was my first installation. My friend tried to install but run into same problems so it seems installing groovy is not possible using listed installation method at all so maybe I should ask how to install Groovy to new Windows computer?

Comment: There is no error message btw. I get icons on desktop that target: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\groovyConsole.vbs" but nothing happens when I click it.